# NgRx: How can I get an individual record based on route params?

Tags: angular, ngrx

In my component I was able to get a record by id using the following code:

```
// component.ts

public activity$: Observable<Activity> = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((params) =>
        this._activityService.getActivity(params['activityId'])
    )
);
```

I'm able to store & retrieve all `activities` from the store like this:

```
// component.ts

public activities$: Observable<Activity[]> = this._store.select(getActivities);
```

I am familiar with [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) so using a store isn't completely unfamiliar.

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to get the current activity like this:

```
// component.ts

public activity$: Observable<Activity | undefined> = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((params) => this._store.pipe(
         select(getSelectedActivity(params['activityId']))
            )
        )
    );
```

My reducer looks like this:

```
// reducer.ts

const activityFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ActivityState>('activities');

...

export const getSelectedActivityId = createSelector(
    activityFeatureState,
    (state) => {
        return state.selectedActivityId;
    }
);


export const getSelectedActivity = createSelector(
    activityFeatureState,
    getSelectedActivityId,
    (state, selectedActivityId) => {
        console.log('selectedActivityId', selectedActivityId);  // undefined
        return state.activities.find(
            (activity) => activity.id === selectedActivityId
        );
    }
);
```

Through other SO threads, I came across [this link](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors). I've also been following the fantastic NgRx guide on PluralSight to help get me this far. I am just completely lost.

I am able to get the `activity` going through a service, and now I'd like to dispatch an effect to get the activity. How can I use my existing service call to get an `activity` from the store?

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadKamran - I was, yes. Mainly that I wasn't correctly passing the arguments from my component and/or not setting up the reducer correctly to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Although my solution works well, I am not 100% sold this is something that is copy/paste worthy for others. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Here is what my component looks like:

```
// component.ts

public activity$: Observable<Activity | undefined> = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((params) =>
        this._store.select(getSelectedActivity(params['activityId']))
    )
);

...

constructor(
        private readonly _store: Store<State>,
        private readonly _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private readonly _activityService: ActivityService
    ) {
        //...
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```
// reducer.ts

...

const activityFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ActivityState>('activities');

export const getActivities = createSelector(
    activityFeatureState,
    (state) => state.activities
);

export const getSelectedActivityId = createSelector(
    activityFeatureState,
    (state) => {
        return state.selectedActivityId;
    }
);

export const getSelectedActivity = (id: string) =>
    createSelector(activityFeatureState, getSelectedActivityId, (state) => {
        return state.activities.find((activity) => activity.id === id);
    });
```

Where I believe I was going wrong is this: `getSelectedActivity = (id: string) =>...`

I am now able to at least pass the id from the route params to the store.